# Positional operator and field limitation

Tags: mongodb

In a find query projection, fields I specify after the positional operator are ignored and the whole document is always returned.

`'myArray.$.myField' : 1` behave exactly like `'myArray.$' : 1`

the positional operator selects the right document. But this document is quite big.  I would like to project only 1 field from it.

Exemple:

```
db.getCollection('match').find({"participantsData.id" : 0001}, { 'participantsData.$.id': 1,  })
```

here the response I have

```
{
    "_id" : "myid",
    "matchCreation" : 1463916465614,
    "participantsData" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 0001,
            "plenty" : "of",
            "other" : "fields",
            "and" : "subdocuments..."
        }
     ]
}
```

This is what I want

```
{
   "_id" : "myid",
    "matchCreation" : 1463916465614,
    "participantsData" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 0001
        }

    ]
}
```

Is it possible with mongo?

Comment: What do want to do if you have two sub-documents with `id: 1` in your array? Do you want to return only the `id` field or part of the sub-document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done in mongo
Please try the below query

```
db.getCollection('match').find(
    {"participantsData.id" : 0001}, 
    {"participantsData.id": 1, "matchCreation": 1 })
```

This will give you the below result

```
{
        "_id" : "myid",
        "matchCreation" : 1463916465614,
        "participantsData" : [
                {
                        "id" : 1
                }
        ]
}
```